# Backstage - getting error while running both frontend and backend using docker-compose

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, backstage

I have been trying to run the frontend, backend and postgres using docker-compose. I am able to successfully build the backstage image following https://github.com/Rugvip/backstage-prod-diff/blob/master/DIFF.md . but when i run it using docker-compose, i am getting this strange error.

```
> developer-portal-backstage-1  | {"code":"EADDRNOTAVAIL","config":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","User-Agent":"axios/0.21.4"},"maxBodyLength":-1,"maxContentLength":-1,"method":"get","timeout":0,"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"transitional":{"clarifyTimeoutError":false,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"silentJSONParsing":true},"url":"undefined","xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN"},"message":"connect EADDRNOTAVAIL ::1:80 - Local (:::0)","stack":"Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL ::1:80 - Local (:::0)\n    at internalConnect (node:net:1041:16)\n    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (node:internal/async_hooks:464:18)\n    at node:net:1134:9\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)"}
>
```

my docker-compose config

```
version: '3'
services:
  backstage:
    image: backstage
    ports:
      - '7007:7007'
    depends_on:
    - db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      LOG_LEVEL: error

  db:
   image: postgres
   environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: postgres
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

I am expecting my entityProvider scripts to work and ingest data. The scripts work when running them locally using yarn dev, but get this error when running the docker-compose.

the scripts are being called, but then are not processing. The connect message is when it enters the connect function in entityProvider and run is when it enter run function